# MudAutoComplete : Problem to get current text without any suggest selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, mudblazor

I'm using MudAutoComplete to implement suggestions based on user entering text, It works perfectly.
My problem is that when user write a text & press Enter, in KeyDown eventHandler i've get the first suggestion in the list instead of current text which user entered!!
For example, when user enter "Alfki", The following suggestions show :
Hi Alfki
Alfki Bye..
Alfki Bye 2

Now, when user hit Enter after Alfki, In KeyDown eventHandler, I've got "Hi Alfki" in bound-value instead of "Alfki"!
Where is my problem and how to solve it?
Thanks ...

**Updated ..**
Here is my sample code :

```
<MudAutocomplete T="string" 
                 Variant="Variant.Outlined"
                 @ref="@_txtAutoCompelete"
                 ResetValueOnEmptyText="true"
                 CoerceText="true"
                 @bind-Text="_strSearchQuery"
                 SearchFunc="@SearchQuery"
                 OnKeyUp="@SearchQueryResult"
                 Adornment="Adornment.End"
                 AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Filled.Search"
                 AdornmentColor="Color.Success">
</MudAutocomplete>

@code{
private string _strSearchQuery;
    private async Task SearchQueryResult(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.Code == "Enter" || e.Code == "NumpadEnter")
            {
                    string strText = _txtAutoCompelete.Text; // first suggestion, not current text!
                    string strValue = _txtAutoCompelete.Value; // first suggestion, not current text!
                    string strCurrentText = _strSearchQuery; // first suggestion, not current text!
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide minimal code to work on

Comment: Of course! I've updated my first post ...

Comment: I think you need to read the [documentation on MudBlazor Autocomplete](https://mudblazor.com/components/autocomplete#api) because it sounds like you have `CoerceValue` set to `false` and you really want it to be `true`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but as u see in my code, i've set CoerceText to true, However i'm facing the same problem!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I've create a custom component based on other mud controls such as popup, mudTextField, etc to make suitable of my requirements.